# Perl script compiled as Windows executable does not connect to Oracle

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

I have a Perl Script that I've written that connects to Oracle. The script works perfectly on my machine with PERL64 installed. I tried to turn this script into an EXE using ActiveState PerlApp. Again, works perfectly on my machine. Once the executable is on a machine that does not contain Perl it is missing DLL's needed to connect to Oracle.

```
use DBI;

    # CONFIG VARIABLES
our $database = "database.app.net";
our $host = "server.app.net";
our $port = "1522";
our $user = "SVC_app";
our $pw = 'Password';

# DATA SOURCE NAME
our $dsn = "dbi:Oracle:$host:$port/$database";

# PERL DBI CONNECT
our $connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw);

# PREPARE THE QUERY
our $query = 'SELECT Blah FROM database."table" where "blah" = ?';
our $query_handle = $connect->prepare($query);

# EXECUTE THE QUERY
$query_handle->execute($value);

# BIND TABLE COLUMNS TO VARIABLES
$query_handle->bind_columns(undef, \$return);

# LOOP THROUGH RESULTS
while($query_handle->fetch()) {
   #print "$return";
}
```

The error i receive is :

**Can't load 'auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.dll' for module DBD::Oracle: load_file:The specified module could not be found at/DynaLoader.pm line 224.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never used PerlApp, but [the docs](http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/6.0/PerlApp.html#perlapp__2d_2dbind_file) suggest you might be able to use the `--bind` option to include additional DLLs. I'm not sure whether you would then need code to load them or if they'd be found automatically.

Comment: I've tried the bind option, it does appear to include the dll and throw it in the temp directory. But the app doesn't know it's there.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases:

- If you do NOT have the DLL files on the target machine, it's not going to work. DLL files aren't linked into the executables (as the name says, they're Dynamic Link Libraries, not static libraries)
- If you DO have the DLL files on the target machine, but they're not found then there are a few possible explanations. The files may not be in the PATH, for instance. Or the files may not have the correct permissions, especially if you're calling your executable from something like a service (which by default runs on a system account which has different permissions).

Also, keep in mind that Window is a bit picky about DLL files. It may say that Oracle.dll is missing, but what is actually missing may be one of its dependencies. Maybe OCI.dll ?
And if you have more than one DLL file with the same name, try and make sure which one is loaded, because it may not be the right version.

If the files are there, there's only one version of them, they're in the PATH and it still cannot find them, you can try registering the files manually by running the `regsvr32` command on the required DLL.

Comment: There's no way to wrap them up in the executable?

Comment: To do that, you would need Oracle static libraries but, unless something changed recently, Oracle does not provide static libraries for Windows. See https://community.oracle.com/thread/2495648?tstart=0 . (And even having them, this is not a standard C/C++ application built with Visual C++ )

Comment: What about using this option I discovered on another script to combine DLL's **--bind PerlEz.dll[file=\perl\bin\PerlEz.dll,extract]**

Comment: I would really like to avoid installing PERL or Oracle.dll's on these machines. They utilize they're own oracle database. I fear adding more oracle files could confuse the machine to which to use. Ideally, the .exe will use its own files

Comment: If you look at the docs that @Grant McLean linked, they say "The bound file is extracted into the TEMP directory upon application start". It depends on when the extraction takes place, whether it's before or after loading dependencies for the app. And even if it was before that, it would be the same as copying the file by yourself, which means multiple versions of the file on the machine.

Comment: The only way that I can see this working is if you have multiple applications that connect to the database and the required DLL files are in the same directory as the executables, for each application, because priority is given to libraries in the same directory. But that would easily become hard to maintain.

Comment: So if I did put them in one directory, they would have to be registered correct? Also, how would I change where DBI looks for those DLL's?

Comment: What you want is "Search Order for Desktop Applications" in this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to separately install the Oracle client on any machine that you are running your EXE on.

PerlApp in the ActiveState's PDK will not wrap Oracle clients into the EXE because doing so will violate Oracle's re-distribution agreement.